# Find any element whose value = X and report path to root

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have data like this:

```xml
<people>
    <person id="1">
        <july>busy</july>
    </person>
    <person id="2">
        <july>
            <Fridays>busy</Fridays>
        </july>
    </person>
    <person id="3">
        <july>
            <Fridays>
                <afternoons>busy</afternoons>
            </Fridays>
        </july>
    </person>
</people>
```

I want to to find all elements whose text = 'busy', and then report their paths back to the root.

I haven't even found how to just print elements yet.

`//[text() = "busy"]`

gives

```
[false()]
[false()]
[false()]
[true()]
[false()]
[false()]
[false()]
[true()]
[false()]
[false()]
[false()]
[false()]
[true()]
[false()]
```

`//*[. = 'busy']!path()` from  Martin Honnen comes very close!

```
/Q{}people[1]/Q{}person[1]
/Q{}people[1]/Q{}person[1]/Q{}july[1]
/Q{}people[1]/Q{}person[2]
/Q{}people[1]/Q{}person[2]/Q{}july[1]
/Q{}people[1]/Q{}person[2]/Q{}july[1]/Q{}Fridays[1]
/Q{}people[1]/Q{}person[3]
/Q{}people[1]/Q{}person[3]/Q{}july[1]
/Q{}people[1]/Q{}person[3]/Q{}july[1]/Q{}Fridays[1]
/Q{}people[1]/Q{}person[3]/Q{}july[1]/Q{}Fridays[1]/Q{}afternoons[1]
```

I guess I would prefer something that only shows the longest path for each person? I'm not crazy about the `Q{}`s, but that's a much lower priority.

```
/Q{}people[1]/Q{}person[1]/Q{}july[1]
/Q{}people[1]/Q{}person[2]/Q{}july[1]/Q{}Fridays[1]
/Q{}people[1]/Q{}person[3]/Q{}july[1]/Q{}Fridays[1]/Q{}afternoons[1]
```

Comment: Interesting, the second person on the same day using `/[boolean expression]` instead of e.g. `foo[boolean expression]`. I think you want `//*[. = 'busy']!path()`.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a common mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess from your comment that your parser chops white-space so you want `//*[not(*) and . = 'busy']!path()`, to make sure you just select leaf elements.

Comment: You could also do `//text()[.='busy']/..!path()`

Comment: Or `(//*[. = 'busy']=>innermost())!path()` would also work.

Comment: One more: `//*[text() = 'busy'] ! path()`. `text()` will be faster than `.`, as the comparisons will only be performed on text nodes.